# How do I remove a module in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, progressive-web-apps

Am new to Angular, so please be gentle.

Ever since I tried turning my angular app into a **PWA** I have been getting this error message:

```
ERROR in Failed to find exported name of node (function NgbAlertModule() {
}) in '/home/sirbt/angular/skuma/pescrow_admin/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert/alert.module.js'.
```

I have decided to do away with this module. Kindly guide me on where to find it and also how to remove this particular module.

Find attached my Angular environment:

[image]

Comment: `npm uninstall package-name-here --save-dev` (or --save-prod)

Comment: @Igor what is the package name? Is it `NgbAlertModule()` or `@ng-bootstrap`?

Comment: `@ng-bootstrap`

Comment: are you using ngx-charts?

Comment: @Igor I run `npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap --save-dev` as you suggested but the error message still persists..

Comment: @AbhishekChokra no I am not, why?

Comment: Did you enable Ivy for your application or did you just go with the default settings?

Comment: @Francesco I went with the default settings. How do I enable Ivy?

Answer (score 1):

npm uninstall  removes the module from node_modules, but not package.json

npm uninstall  --save also removes it from dependencies in package.json

npm uninstall  --save-dev also removes it from devDependencies in package.json

npm -g uninstall  --save also removes it globally

Comment: thank you for your response.  Can you kindly point out what the name of the module is?

Comment: @ng-bootstrap (i guess,i am also new to angular)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [step by step guide to create PWAs with Angular](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular) (plus a working Github example). You can follow it to create your first PWA with ease.

About your question, if you want to remove ngboostrap, you should run this command from your console (and of course you have to remove the references to this library in your code):

```
npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Usually if you install a library in Angular, this will be listed in your `package.json` file. 
Therefore to remove it, you can run the npm command:

```
`npm uninstall package-name`
```

where package-name is the name you see in package.json file.

Comment: Kindly help me with this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140786/how-do-i-git-pull-an-angular-app-to-a-local-angular-pwa-enabled-project]