# How do I Git pull an Angular app to a local Angular-pwa enabled project?

Tags: angular, bitbucket, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I created an angular app which I pushed to my Bitbucket repository. To turn my angular app into a Progressive Web App, I followed this [step by step guide](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular).

The result, was a newly created folder (as per the guide) called **angular-pwa**. I then `cd` into the **angular-pwa** and `pulled` my app from the repository.

The commands I used to `pull` my app:

```
git init .
git remote add origin 
https://myName@bitbucket.org/myName/myAppName.git
git pull origin master
```

I never saw any error messages following the above commands, suggesting that my app was successfully pulled, however, when I `cd` into the `angular-pwa` folder, I don't see any trance of my **pulled** app.

By pulling my app from the repository, I expected everything in the `angular-pwa` folder to be overwritten with my `pulled` app.

Running `ng serve -o --port 4000` also shows the default angular page installed via `ng new angular-pwa` as seen below but **NOT** my app:

the default app installed via `ng new angular-pwa`

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and how to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: I think it might be a mismatch of repositories. What i would suggest to do, is to get the pwa repo (as per link) and then apply eventual edits to that project/source. This is probably the approach with less errors.